# Diagram of Linux kernel vs. performance tools?

Tags: linux, performance

Is there a diagram that shows how the various performance tools such as `ip`, `netstat`, `perf`, `top`, `ps`, etc. interact with the various subsystems within the Linux kernel?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I came across this diagram which shows exactly this.

[image: ss #1]

In the above you can see where tools such as `strace`, `netstat`, etc. interact with the Linux kernel's subsystems. I like this diagram because it succinctly shows where each tool latches on to the Linux kernel, which can be extremely helpful when you're first learning about all the tools and their applications.

**Source:** *[Linux PerfTools](http://www.brendangregg.com/Perf/linuxperftools.png)*

#### References

- [Linux Performance](http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html)

Comment: there are times on this site where I'm a bit confused...as to whether to upvote the question or the answer, so when in doubt i do both! SLM, as always, appreciated

Comment: @1_CR - kind words are always appreciated.

Comment: Just one word: awesome ! And this diagram would remain true for most Unix systems.

Comment: It's missing `ltrace`, but nice diagram.

Comment: `ltrace` is there in the original png ('Source' at the bottom)

Comment: Added updated image that now includes `ltrace`.

Comment: I think `mtr` belongs next to `traceroute`.