# Iotop shows swapin but vmstat si is zero

Tags: virtual-memory

I run `iotop` and `vmstat` on a CentOS server. Under some load the `iotop` *swapin* column starts to display values around 5% to 20% for some processes. But `vmstat` *si* field remains at zero. I thought that `vmstat` *si* and `iotop` *swapin* would both reflect swapping. How can *si* be zero while `iostat` shows significant *swapin*?

**Side note**:

`vmstat` *si*: Amount of memory swapped in from disk (/s)

Comment: If you take a look at the diagram I posted on this Q&A it shows what subsystem of the Linux kernel each of those tools is showing performance data about: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117742/diagram-of-linux-kernel-vs-performance-tools/117743#117743

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the diagram I posted on this U&L Q&A titled: [Diagram of Linux kernel vs. performance tools?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117742/diagram-of-linux-kernel-vs-performance-tools/117743#117743) it shows what subsystem of the Linux kernel each of those tools is showing performance data from.

`iotop` primary purpose is in showing stats from the perspective of the block device interface. So this would be your HDD, for example. While `vmstat` shows stats from the kernel's virtual memory subsystem.

This paragraph from `iotop`'s man page also explains what it's up to:

> iotop  displays columns for the I/O bandwidth read and written by each process/thread during the sampling period. It also displays the percentage
>          of time the thread/process spent while swapping in and while waiting on I/O. For each process, its I/O priority (class/level) is shown.

#### Example

```
Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :      36.93 K/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:       0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND  
  303 be/3 root        0.00 B/s   29.54 K/s  0.00 %  4.42 % [jbd2/dm-1-8]
29559 be/4 saml        0.00 B/s    7.39 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % google-chrome-stable [Chrome_HistoryT]
```

So in the above example jdb2 has spent 4.42% of its time waiting for I/O resources. This is over it's life, not at this particular moment.

The output from `vmstat` is showing the ongoing stats from virtual memory, indicating any pages that are either dirty or need to be pushed/pulled from swap, so you're seeing these pages being shuttled around there. You have no indications from `vmstat` what process these pages belong to, only that there was pages swapped in/out.

```
$ vmstat 5
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 2  0 2990956 1429112  45664 712416    8   15    50   149    7   33 34  5 60  2
 0  0 2990948 1385392  45696 725096    0    0  2009    36  833 1556  6  1 92  1
 0  0 2990948 1380700  45704 726516    0    0     0    16  700 1423  3  1 95  1
 2  0 2990944 1386960  45760 724400    3    0     3   264 1075 1837  5  1 91  3
```

The `si` & `so` columns are the swap related stats.

#### So why does vmstat's si show 0?

The value being reported for si is actually a rate of change value (amount moved per second). See this article titled: 
[Use vmstat to Monitor System Performance](https://www.linode.com/docs/uptime/monitoring/use-vmstat-to-monitor-system-performance):

> The swap section reports the rate that memory is sent to or retrieved
>   from the swap system. By reporting “swapping” separately from total
>   disk activity, vmstat allows you to determine how much disk activity
>   is related to the swap system.
>
> The si column reports the amount of memory that is moved from swap to
>   “real” memory per second. The so column reports the amount of memory
>   that is moved to swap from “real” memory per second.

Given this it's likely that even though a process is reporting that it's using swap through `iostat`, that usage of swap is probably not enough to get picked up over the course of a second that would show up in `vmstat`'s "si" measurement.

Comment: In my understanding this answer doesn't cover why iotop may show non-zero SWAPIN when vmstat shows zeroes in si and so

Comment: @noonex - see update.