# How does netstat command fit in various layers of TCP/IP model in the performance diagram?

Tags: performance, netstat

`netstat` command is useful to,

> Print network connections, routing tables, interface statistics,
>   masquerade connections, and multicast memberships.

Now, I was reading about the Linux performance which is depicted in a nice pictorial view from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117743/47538).

How is `netstat` command used in various levels of networking as depicted in the performance diagram in the referenced question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us look into the performance diagram to understand the various layers in which `netstat` command is useful for debugging.

[image]

**Ethernet**

`netstat -in` command is used in this layer where `-i` flag is used to display a table of all network interfaces, or the specified iface.

**IP**

`netstat -an` command is used in this layer where `-a` flag is used to show both listening and non-listening (for TCP this means established connections) sockets.

**TCP/UDP**

`netstat -at` is used to display either TCP or UDP connections. TCP and UDP protocols are used in the transport layer.

**Sockets**

`netstat -p` is used to show which processes are using which sockets.